# How to transfer my data from one account to other?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

Some time ago I used 'live.com' email, was signing to google with this email and was storing my google drive data with this email.

Then I decided to switch to 'gmail.com' email.

Now I use 'gmail.com' for email and 'live.com' for google drive data and documents.

I want to have everything under one account 'gmail.com'. I know I can download all data to my mac from one account and upload them to another account. I will have to do it in chunks, because I have a lot of data.

Is there more convenient way to get everything under one account?

Comment: I've heard of people using a free GCE VM to do fast Drive-to-Drive transfers ( directly through Google's backbone network), but it wouldn't help with Drive-created docs, only with ordinary files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move all files from account A to account B:

1. Move all files to a folder X in A
2. Right click the folder X, click 'Share' and select 'Transfer Ownership'
3. Follow the process
4. Create folder Y in account B and share with account A
5. In account A right right click X and tap 'Move to'
6. Select the folder Y

Yes, all sharing permissions will be lost :(